# C# Word Interop encoding on pasting HTML from Clipboard

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

In order to paste formatted HTML in a Word document, I am using this approach [HtmlFragment](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2007/01/21/sample-code-html-clipboard.aspx) that was recommended several times here. My problem now is the charset that is not recognized. I already add this in the HtmlFragment to generate proper encode:

```
<meta http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; charset=iso-8859-2"" />
```

Code used for copy/paste:

```
 HtmlFragment.CopyToClipboard(req.Descricao);           
 doc.Application.Selection.Paste();
```

The outpout in Word doc should be like this:

```
separação
```

And I have:

```
separa磯
```

Does anyone have a tip?
Appreciate any help.